# Trying to get GIMP paint studio working on Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, gimp

I have downloaded gimp paint studio [online](https://code.google.com/archive/p/gps-gimp-paint-studio/downloads) and moved the files to `/home/username/.gimp-2.8`. However when I try to cd into any of the brushes etc. I don't have permission.

I tried `chmod ug+x` and then I managed to enter the directory but still wasn't given permission to view any of the files.

I tried directly from the terminal as well but it failed

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shnatsel/gimp-paint-studio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp-paint-studio
```

EDIT: I just did `sudo adduser username www-data` to change my permissions and now it seems to work.

Comment: How exactly did you move the files? was `sudo` involved? what is the *ownership* of the files (`ls -l ~/.gimp-2.8/`)?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes sudo was involved. I did sudo cp -r * to the gimp directory. upon ls -l I get : drwxr-xr-x 2 username username    4096 okt 27 18:05 brushes .. and so on for all the folders.

Comment: Do not use sudo unless you know that you have to use sudo.